# XNA - Read Tile Maps From Txt file

Tags: arrays, xna, stream, 2d

i've been eperimenting and looking around the internet, but yet i havenn't figured out how to read a tile map from a text file. Basically i have an array called `map`, but i want to load the map from a text file, instead of implementing every single level in classes :/

The game im thinking on is a puzzle game, you're an rpg character, and have to solve puzzles to be able to enter the new room.

So how would i make so when i want to add a new map / level, i simply just have to write a new .txt file and add it into the Game1.cs or anything like that? 
Thanks in advance :P

Comment: Uffe - the RPG tag is for the RPG programming language, not for "Role Playing Games".

Comment: The only way I can to something like this is using XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noamg97's answer correctly describes how to read and write text files in .NET, but it's worth noting that there are more concise ways to write both of his examples:

```
string[] mapData = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

And

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, mapData);
```

Assuming that each character represents one tile on your map, you can quickly convert the `mapData` array above into a more convenient format for processing into your native data format using a simple loop:

```
var width = mapData[0].Length;
var height = mapData.Length;
var tileData = new char[width, height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        tileData[x, y] = mapData[y][x];
}
```

Which you can then use to determine the character for a specific tile with a simple lookup.

Comment: I have my level1.txt in my content/levels folder, and i replaced my array with: ``string[] mapData = File.ReadAllLines("Levels/level1");``
and i got this: Error 1 Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "Levels\level1.txt". There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project. 
Any ideas? I guess i'm missing something big...

Comment: It's trying to feed your text file through the XNA Content Pipeline.  Select the file in the Solution Explorer and view its properties, then change its Build Action to 'None' and its Copy to Output Directory setting to 'Copy if newer'

Comment: Also, you'll need to change the path to "Content/Levels/level1"

Comment: Thanks, now theres only one thing, the draw function, i get an error,
_Syntax Error; value expected_ . Before i had the map[y, x],

But now when i used the text file, it didn't want to have it there..So what should i put? My draw:
``spriteBatch.Draw(tileList[map[]], new Rectangle(x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight), Color.White);``

Comment: You're going to have to convert the data that you read into map data, somehow.  Without knowing how you have it set up I can't tell you specifics.  The map data that you've read in from the file is just an array of strings containing the text.

Comment: This is my setup for the tile engine:http://www.jtmbooks.com/rpgtutorials/rpgtutorial1.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35612/discussion-between-uffe-puffe-and-cole-campbell)

Answer (score 0):

Easily, to read from a .txt file all you have to do is use some tools from the System.IO namespace:

```
using (System.IO.Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(Path_String, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string line = null;
    while (true)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();

        //Get Your Map Data

        if (line == null)
            break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to write a .txt file in C#, use the following code:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path + "/" + newShow.name + ".txt");
writer.Write(dataToRight);
writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();
```

**EDIT:** Additional information - to get your map data from a text file to an array, you could use something like the following code (that assumes that you are indeed storing your map data as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271747/xna-rpg-collision-and-camera )

```
List<int[]> temp = new List<int[]>();
List<int> subTemp = new List<int>();
```

...

```
string line = null;
while (true)
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();

    while (line.IndexOf(',') != -1)
    {
        subTemp.Add(line[0]);
        line.Substring(1);
    }
    temp.Add(subTemp.ToArray());
    if (line == null)
        break;
}

int[][] mapData = temp.ToArray();
```